# ElasticMQ does not reject illegal string as epected

Tags: amazon-sqs, elastic-mq

I have been using ElasticMQ, it is supposed to behave like AWS SQS.

- According to AWS SQS online documentation, any illegal strings that are out of this range #x9 | #xA | #xD | #x20 to #xD7FF | #xE000 to #xFFFD | #x10000 to #x10FFFF, will be rejected.

But when I created an illegal string (only consists of one illegal char), and sent it to ElasticMQ, it was not rejected.

- ElasticMQ did behave strangely though: for this illegal string (one char), the MD5 checksum calculated on the client side was very different from the MD5 checksum returned by ElasticMQ.

Can anyone verify if ElasticMQ is able to reject illegal strings?

Comment: What was the value of the illegal character, and what were the two MD5 hashes?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, the illegal char was randomly generated outside of allowed this range, #x9 | #xA | #xD | #x20 to #xD7FF | #xE000 to #xFFFD | #x10000 to #x10FFFF

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot,I just ran my program, this time, the illegal character is 뱉, 1456389193 (in decimal), MD5 calculated by the client is d1457b72c3fb323a2671125aef3eab5d, MD5 returned is 50d1e45cc11dfb47df3355bef6a43fb0